# Is it possible to bind to a knockout property to options datepickerOptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/jmogera/g9cNL/1/

I have posted this example on what I am trying to do. I basically want to bind to the datapickeroptions with a knockout property. I want to change the minDate as certain flag is set to true.

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: myDate, datepickerOptions: { minDate: date }" />


var viewModel = {
    date: ko.observable(new Date()),
    myDate: ko.observable(new Date("09/01/2011")),
    setToCurrentDate: function() {
        this.myDate(new Date());
    }
};
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Inside the custom binding use just use the allBindingAccessor

```
var allBindings = allBindingAccessor();
var dateOptions = allBindings.datePickerOptions;
var minDate = dateOptions.minDate;
```

Comment: would that go in line 4 and 5 in my example? Also how I set the new minDate?